# ArsClassica and TOC

Tags: classicthesis, arsclassica

in the TOC using the ArsClassica package I always get the error from chapter 10 onwards that the second digit is not at the same level as the first. That looks terrible. I have already found out that the reason for this is the integrated pdfspacing option of ClassicThesis. However, if I comment this out, I get a lot of errors when compiling my 200-page thesis. Is there an alternative? Please look at the MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Test}
    \chapter{Test}
    \chapter{Test}
    \chapter{Test}
    \chapter{Test}
    \chapter{Test}
    \chapter{Test}
    \chapter{Test}
    \chapter{Test}
    \chapter{Test}
    \chapter{Test}
    \chapter{Test}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just two notes: `classicthesis` is not really `scrreprt` compatible. IMHO you should not use this combination. There is a comment in `classicthesis.sty`, that option `pdfspacing` is obsolete.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I find the following there: `OBSOLETE; use pdftex for letterspacing (via microtype)`. What to do with that? If I comment out pdfspacing, I get errors that are incomprehensible to me, e.g. `ArsClassica.tex: Argument of \markboth has an extra }.`

Comment: Sorry, I cannot see another problem than the compatibility warnings, if I comment the `classicthesis` line in your example. And with `report` instead of `scrreprt` there are even less warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well while the option `pdfspacing` has been declared obsolete, in combination with arsclassica you should probably keep it, as without it arsclassica will use the soul package and that is rather fragile.

You get the two different digit as there is a brace missing in the `\numberline` command, and so the font command of classicthesis affects only the first digit. In combination with the iwona font that is quite visible.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\makeatletter
\cftchapnumwidth=1cm %more space after the number
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{%
  \hb@xt@\@tempdima{\@cftbsnum{#1}\@cftasnum\hfil}\@cftasnumb}
\makeatother  
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{chapter}{8}    
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to adapt the definition of `\ttl@addcontentsline` from `classicthesis` to specify `\scshape` for the full number:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\makeatletter
\cftchapnumwidth=1cm %more space after the number
\def\ttl@addcontentsline#1#2{% this is from titlesec.sty
  \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{\scshape\ifttl@toclabel\ttl@a\fi{\upshape#2}}% write titles as a group inside {}
  \nobreak}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Test}
    \chapter{Test}
    \chapter{Test}
    \chapter{Test}
    \chapter{Test}
    \chapter{Test}
    \chapter{Test}
    \chapter{Test}
    \chapter{Test}
    \chapter{Test}
    \chapter{Test}
    \chapter{Test}  
\end{document}
```

The output is the same as in the answer by Ulrike.